# problems runing Android Studio Flamingo Version

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm developing a project in a computer which has Android Studio Electric Eel Version. I want to continue the project in my personal computer, which has Android Studio Flamingo Version. When I open the app and try to upload a code (into even my project, it also happens with the default code of Android Studio). It shows approximately 520 errors.

I don't know how to proceed.

Also, when I try to open an xml file, it doesn't show the image of the screen and all the components.

I tried to reinstall the program 3 times and happens the same

[Errors pt.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUyTQ.png)

[Errors pt.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj9ti.png)

[Link to the project located in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A4xCyZ-SVBlW3VUQK4WFprYu4R06wF-5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide some errors from the stack trace ? Without errors we can't help you since we can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I attached some photos below

Comment: Are you sure you have the right SDK in your pc and using it correctly in your project ? 
To check: File -> Project Structure -> SDK and Project.
 Check if you are using the latest Gradle and AGP versions. If so, check for the SDK

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where are the photos showing the problem?

Comment: I have just put the "Android Gradle Plugin Version" at 8.0.2, my "Gradle Version" at 8.2 and the "Compile sdk version" at 33. I tried to com pile again and happened the same.

Comment: I uploded my project to google drive and pasted the link in the article in case omeone can help me or take a look and find the solution.